# Angular 2 - Output strange error

Tags: angular, angular-components

I get a strange error when using @Output

Output declaration

```
@Output() change: EventEmitter = new EventEmitter();
```

Emitting Value

```
this.change.emit('string');
```

Event listener

```
<selective (change)="getDataAreas($event)"></selective>
```

Do I forget someting?

When I add the last command (change) I always get this error to the console

```
TypeError: instance[output.propName].subscribe is not a function
```

FYI

The emit is inside this code

```
this.sub = this.searchField.valueChanges
        .startWith('')
        .debounceTime(200)
        .subscribe((result) => {
            this.change.emit(result);
        });
```

Comment: What is `this.searchField.valueChanges`?

Comment: this.searchField = new FormControl();

Comment: I don't have problems with the observable. It works as I expect...

Comment: In which component do you define the `@Output() change`? Can you give more detail or maybe share the code of these 2 components (listener and emitter)?

Comment: Selective Component

Comment: Can you try changing the name of your event? Rather than `(change)` maybe make it `(selectivechange)` and try again?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/k5xwao1u/

https://jsfiddle.net/cq4s8juz/1/

Comment: I have already try to change the name... but.. no.. it doesn't work

Comment: Still the same error when you change the event name? Because "change" might be reserved keyword for events.

Comment: I found the error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found it...

PHP Storm auto generate wrong import path

```
import {EventEmitter} from "events"; // Wrong

import {EventEmitter} from '@angular/core'; // Right
```

Comment: PHP Storm does ask you before it adds the import statement. You should wisely select which one to use.